# Unable to turn JSON to Dictionary in python from get request

Tags: python, json, dictionary, get

I am trying to turn json I got from a GET request using an API into a dictionary that I can use. Here is what I did:

```
response = requests.get(API)
response_dict = json.loads(response.json())
print(response_dict)
```

I get the error:

```
raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

Comment: Did you look at `response.json()`?

Comment: The `.json()` returns a loaded python object, not a string. for that you'd use `.text` i believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carefully read the error. It suggests that `response.json()` already returns a `dict`. There is no need to call `json.loads` (which accepts a string) on it.

```py
response = requests.get(API)
response_dict = response.json()
```

is all you need.